# get value from scroll in data table vuetify 2

Tags: javascript, datatable, vuejs2, lazy-loading, vuetify.js

I am trying to use scrolling directive in a data table, but this doesn't work, I need to get value to implement a "lazy load" since rendering takes a long time when I load a lot of data and I need the user to only move the mouse and not change the page.

Data Table

```
<v-data-table 
:headers="headerTable" 
:items="filterContent" 
:height="maximumHeight" 
id="scroll-target"
v-scroll="onScroll"></v-data-table>
```

Method

```
onScroll (e) {
    this.offsetTop = e.target.scrollTop;
},
```

Comment: where do you put the lazy load function?

Comment: I have a computed variable "filterContent", with the data in the table, but I would like to have the value of the scroll to be able to indicate which will be shown and which will not and reduce the rendering time, it is the only option that occurred to me.